# Trying to initialize the account with the space argument provided by the instruction

Tags: anchor, account

The game can be played between 1-20 players. I am saving the pubkeys of the players in `pub players: Vec<Pubkey>`. In order to determine the space required for the account, I am trying to achieve optimization in the following way:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(players: usize)]
pub struct InitGame<'info> {
    #[account(init,payer=signer,space= 8 + 8 + 2 + 32 + 4 + players * 8)]
    pub game: Account<'info,Game>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>
}
```

Although, the program is compiling just fine but when I try to test it, get the following error which is most probably due to the wrong space configuration:

```
'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.'
```

Comment: Can you share your test code, together with the input params for the instruction taking the InitGame context? - That would be very useful.

Comment: @Meow Please read my answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the problem. The problem was with the data type of `player` argument. We can only use `usize` data type for `space` but since anchor doesn't map `usize` for TS/JS, we can't pass the argument with the type of `usize`.

To address the issue, I passed u8 data type in the instruction and then converted u8 to usize within the InitGame context like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(players: u8)]
pub struct InitGame<'info> {
    #[account(init,payer=signer,space= {
        let players_size = players as usize;

        8 + 8 + 2 + 32 + 4 + players_size * 8
    })]
    pub game: Account<'info,Game>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>
}
```

Tests are passing and client is successfully creating the game account now, however, I am not sure if this is the best way to address the issue. I would like to hear from the experienced folk here if this leaves any security vulnerability behind the scene for Anchor.